# Display Doctrine Collection with twig ? (Symfony2)

Tags: doctrine, symfony, twig

I have a quite simple doctrine entity that represent a news ; this news can be linked with many pictures, so I decided to use a Doctrine Collection. The thing is, I want to retrieve this pictures and display them in my template... But it didn't seem to work. Do you know how I can do that ?

Here is what I tried :

```
{% for annonce in annonces %}
    <div class="annonce_item">
    {% for photo in annonce.photo  %}
        <img src="{{ photo.path }}" alt="" />
    {% endfor %}
</div>
<!-- End .annonce_item -->
{% endfor %}
```

*annonce* is the news class, and *photo* is the collection :

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Photo", mappedBy="id",cascade={"persist"})
 */

private $photo;
```

When I try to display this page in my browser, I get this exception:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Undefined index: >id in >/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ApacheImmobilier/vendor/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/Basi>cEntityPersister.php line 1274") in "APPagesBundle:Index:index.html.twig" at line 45.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Read [this article of the doc](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/association-mapping.html). It says:

> The mappedBy attribute designates the field in the entity that is the
>   owner of the relationship.

which, in your case, must be the `news` field of your Photo entity.

Comment: Voted down because the user asked for a solution in twig template file for working with collections.

Comment: What the troll ? The answer is implicit because it is simple : just do like in the question, but without the mistake explained in the answer.

Comment: This helped me find a bug with a similar error message. This answer is absolutely on point and related to the question.